# For single insert Operation some Record inserting twice

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-2008

I have  created one method `insert_detail` and in that method only one time insert operation is  perform for each table based on condition but for some record it insert twice and make duplication in database and this issue came for one week only. So please help me to find the solution for that.

```
Private Sub insert_detail(mservice_order_no, mprod_code, malt_prod_code, mqty, mtype, mfrom_original_hub, maxno)
On Error GoTo ErrTrap
    Dim mcmt As String
    Dim strSQL$

    If mfrom_original_hub = "TRUE" Then
        mcmt = "Y"
    Else
        mcmt = "N"
    End If

    strSQL = ""
    If mtype = "A" Then
        strSQL = "insert into service_order_alt_parts(fk_num_service_ord_no,fk_var_orig_prod_code," & _
            "fk_var_alt_prod_code,num_alt_prod_qty,num_flag,commited,From_CPL) " & _
            "values('" & mservice_order_no & "','" & mprod_code & "','" & malt_prod_code & "'," & _
            mqty & "," & maxno & ",'" & mcmt & "','TRUE')"

    ElseIf mtype = "R" Then
        strSQL = "insert into service_order_repl_parts(fk_num_service_ord_no,fk_var_orig_prod_code," & _
            "fk_var_repl_prod_code,num_repl_prod_qty,num_flag,commited,From_CPL) " & _
            "values('" & mservice_order_no & "','" & mprod_code & "','" & malt_prod_code & "'," & _
            mqty & "," & maxno & ",'" & mcmt & "','TRUE')"
    End If

    If strSQL <> "" Then conn.Execute strSQL

ErrTrap:
    If Err Then
        If Err.Number <> 5555 Then _
            Call WriteToCommonLog("insert_detail", Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description & " - " & strSQL)

        Err.Raise 55555, , ""
    End If
End Sub
```

And I am calling that insert_detail in:-

```
If mstock_found = True Then
    search_for_alternate_parts_from_cpl = 1

    maxno = get_max_no(mservice_order_no, mprod_code, "A")
    For i = 1 To alt_collection.Count
        Call add_parts_to_collection(alt_collection.Item(i), "A", alt_qty_collection.Item(i))
        Call insert_detail(mservice_order_no, mprod_code, alt_collection.Item(i), alt_qty_collection.Item(i), "A", mfrom_original_hub, maxno)

        Call WriteToDebugLog("search_for_alternate_parts_from_cpl -> StockFound", mservice_order_no & " : " & mprod_code & " : (A)" & alt_collection.Item(i) & " : " & alt_qty_collection.Item(i) & " : " & mfrom_original_hub)
        If mfrom_original_hub = "TRUE" Then
            str3 = "update product with (RowLock) set commited=commited + " & CInt(alt_qty_collection.Item(i)) & " where productcode='" & alt_collection.Item(i) & "' and whseid='" & mwhseid & "'"
            conn.Execute (str3)
        End If
    Next i

    If mfrom_original_hub = "TRUE" Then
        str3 = "update Service_Order_Detail with (RowLock) set chr_ignore='Y' where fk_num_service_ord_no='" & mservice_order_no & "' and fk_var_orig_prod_code='" & mprod_code & "' "
        conn.Execute (str3)

        str3 = "update service_order_alt_parts with (RowLock) set chr_ignore='Y' where fk_num_service_ord_no='" & mservice_order_no & "' and fk_var_orig_prod_code='" & mprod_code & "' and num_flag <>" & maxno
        conn.Execute (str3)
    End If

    Set alt_collection = Nothing
    Set alt_qty_collection = Nothing
Else
    Set alt_collection = Nothing
    Set alt_qty_collection = Nothing

    search_for_alternate_parts_from_cpl = 0
End If
```

Comment: There's nowt in that code than I can see. Might be wise to look further up the chain. If it's not obvious, perhaps some check doesn't exist code before the insert attempt, or a unique key (if you have one) on the table(s)

Comment: this issue came only in last week before that this issue has not came this code is last modify in 2008

Comment: I see `Call WriteToDebugLog(...`. Are that doubled inserts _logged_ twice as well?

Comment: Please use proper tags in the future, that's neither classic ASP nor VBScript. It's something known as ASP.NET, written in VB.NET.

Comment: @JosefZ Call WriteToDebugLog(ByVal sFunctionName As String, ByVal sLogMsg As String) is just functionname which i am passing

Comment: Is that `WriteToDebugLog` a function name  _only_ with no meaning? I'd expect it writes parameters to a log _file_ or something alike...

Comment: I strongly suggest you learn to use parameterized queries and stop building queries by concatenating strings. Have you ever heard of "SQL Injection" attacks?

Comment: No I have never heared about SQL Injecction Attack.